# How to link to a "pinned to homescreen" webapp on iOs?

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm working on a SinglePageApplication (JS+HTML) project. 
The webapp is pinned to the homescreen on an iphone.
This application calls a native app called "pic2shop" to scan a barcode with a registered custom scheme like this:

```
window.uri=pic2shop://scan?callback=localhost:20001%3Feancode%3DEAN
```

When "pic2shop"is done it calls the uri supllied by the callback parameter.
That's fine!

Thing is, by calling the supplied uri a new instance of safari pops up and opens the uri. What I'd like to see is, that the already running instance of my webapp is reused. Any ideas? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use "Safari View Controller".
And here is a great example how:

https://library.launchkit.io/how-ios-9-s-safari-view-controller-could-completely-change-your-app-s-onboarding-experience-2bcf2305137f#.r1ac0b5c2

**EDIT**

If you want your app to open, with a webView contex, you cand send params on the sheme:

```
//myScheme://params=1&param2=openWebView
```

You will get a call at:

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)ur
```

And then check the param, and open webView if needed:

```
NSString *query = [url query];
NSArray *queryComponents = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
param1=value
NSArray *firstParam = [[queryComponents objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
[firstParam objectAtIndex:0] 
[firstParam objectAtIndex:1]
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear in my question. A 3rd Party App calls an URI and I want that URI to open my pinned webapp. Would Safari Web Controller help in that case?

Comment: So the user is at the contex of A 3rd app? So you want your app to open with webView? So you are looking for passing params on a Scheme?

Comment: The flow is like this:
1. A user is on my webapp (pure HTML+JS pinned to homescreen) and presses a button. 
2. The click event launches a native app by calling the custom scheme. 
3. The native app should call my webapp back. It does by opening a regular URI (http://..../myCallback) which in turn opens Safari but I want it to open my running instance from 1.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean now. So it doesnt matter that your app is HTML+JS behind the scene. It still acts as a real app, a Hybrid Mobile App . So you can use scheme too, You should register a Scheme that will open your app, the same as you  call a scheme to open the native app. Witch framework are you using?

Comment: Well, it's not a hybrid app. I don't have any native iOS code, it's just HTML+JS.

Comment: hybrid app is an app that isn't native. You can be or a hybrid app, or native. Or you are a web page that the user serfed from safari.